# how to return one string as multiple lines in IO?

Tags: haskell, io

I'm trying to create a show' function that will take a list of tuples and return a string that creates a new line after every tuple. So it would take [(x,y),(a,b),(c,d)] and return

x y

a b

c d

what I have so far in terms of code is

```
show' :: [(String,Int)] -> String
show' [] = ""
show' (x:xs) = (fst x) ++ " " ++ (show (snd x)) ++ " something that will create a newline in IO " ++ show' xs
```

Comment: You can represent a newline in Haskell using `"\n"`.

Comment: I've tried that by just putting \n in the open position on the string, but that just returned a string with "\n" in it.

Comment: Compare `show' ...` with `putStrLn $ show' ...`.

Comment: Are you using `print` to write the resulting string to the console? If so, use `putStr` or `putStrLn` instead, since `print` uses `show` internally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newlines in Haskell can be represented with `"\n"`.

If you are still printing strings to the console that contain the character sequence `\n`, it probably means you are using `print`. Use `putStr` or `putStrLn` instead.

You don't want to use `print` because it internally uses `show`, which encodes the literal newline as the characters `\` and `n`. `print` is more useful in debugging than in actual production code.

Answer (score 0):

There is function `unlines` which joins lines and appends newline to each of them. So you can use something like

```
show' :: [(String, Int)] -> String
show' xs = unlines $ map (\(x,y) -> (show x) ++ " " ++ (show y)) xs
```

Use `putStrLn` to print the output otherwise you'll see '\n' instead of newline.